# How to display the "Hello world" using apache using Python using mod_wsgl but without CGI

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I have installed the Python , apache.
The command line programs are working with python.

I have two virtual hosts in apache

```
site1.local
site2.local
```

WHat i want is i place file in site1 root directory and it display hello in browser

with mod_wsgl only without cgi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In it's most simplest form..

Create a file called `hello_world.wsgi` with the following contents. This should be outside of your `DocumentRoot` so that Apache is unable to serve it up as plain text:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Then configure your vhost to serve all requests beneath `/` from that script:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / <path_to_script>/hello_world.wsgi
```

Comment: i am trying that and will let u know. Thanks for being simple and straight to point

Comment: Thanks buddy i finally displayed hello in browser. I am confused with one thing , i was epecting to run something like hello.py and now i am running wsgi so it means on web i can't have something like hello.py and with code in it. Where will i write my all code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually tried reading the mod_wsgi documentation. That is what it is there for.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp

Comment: From the man himself no less!